# Use jQuery to set a variable for a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, datepicker

I have a little problem mixing a JavaScript library (Polymaps) and jQuery.
I'd like to call a different file everytime the user selects a value from the datepicker.

The filename syntax is:

```
4sq_'the selected day value' _ 'the selected month value'.json
```

This is the datepicker code:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
    inline: true,
    minDate: new Date(2011, 8 - 1, 20),
    maxDate:new Date(2011, 12 - 1, 31),
    altField: '#datepicker_value',
      onSelect: function(){
        var selDay = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getDate();                 
        var selMonth = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getMonth() + 1;             
        var selYear = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getFullYear();

        plotMap()
    }
});
```

and the name of the file contains the values of the selection like below:

```
function plotMap(){
    map.add(po.geoJson()
       .url("4sq_"+selDay+"_"+selMonth+".json")
       .on("load", loadAreas));
};
```

I also tried the code:

```
function plotMap(){
    map.add(po.geoJson()
       .url("4sq_"+
                   $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getDate()
            +"_"+
                  $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getMonth()
            +".json")
       .on("load", loadAreas));
};
```

but it throws me an `Access to restricted URI denied` error.

What I'm doing wrong? Any suggestion?

Comment: In the network tab of Chrome dev console or Firebug, can you see what URL it is trying to access?  Are you sure it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
    inline: true,
    minDate: new Date(2011, 8 - 1, 20),
    maxDate:new Date(2011, 12 - 1, 31),
    altField: '#datepicker_value',
      onSelect: function(){
        var selDay = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getDate();                 
        var selMonth = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getMonth() + 1;

        plotMap(selDay, selMonth);
    }
});

function plotMap(day, month){
    map.add(po.geoJson()
       .url("4sq_"+day+"_"+month+".json")
       .on("load", loadAreas));
}
```

Comment: It seems not working.I get the same error. _Access to restricted URI denied_
**req.send(null);**

Comment: try alerting the url: example: `alert("4sq_"+day+"_"+month+".json"); in the plotMap function

Comment: Uh ok I figured out. The problem was that the name of the file was "4sq_07_09.json" the value of the datepicker during the selection seemed correct "07/09/2011" but checking with firebug the variables 'day' and 'month' were 7 and 9 (without 0). Tha's why the url sent was incorrect. The script was trying to reach the "4sq_7_9.json" file that didn't exist

Answer (score 0):

The error implies that you are violating the [Single Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), i.e. you're trying to access a cross-domain URL.

Looking at your URL, it does not seem like a cross-domain one. It is possible that when Polymap is trying to use absolute URL and somehow produces a bug in translation. You may want to step through how Polymap does the `.url()` function, starting at line 184 in [the latest source](https://github.com/simplegeo/polymaps/blob/master/polymaps.js).

One way to check whether the JSON is indeed on a different origin is to look at the requests in your Firebug or Web Inspector and see whether the requests made to the JSON files are indeed in the same domain according to the [origin determination rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules); for example, http://www.example.com is different origin than http://example.com.